# When should I attach the indirect and direct object pronoun to the end of a verb?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, enclisis

I was wondering if you should ever attach the indirect and direct object pronoun to a conjugated verb, and if so, when that would occur?

For example, let's say I wanted to convert "La maestra da un examen a nosotros" to use the indirect and direct object pronouns:

> La maestra nos lo da.
>
> La maestra danoslo.

Which should I use?

Comment: "[...] da un examen a nosotros" is not correct. It should be "[...] nos da un examen (a nosotros)".

Comment: As far as I know, when a teacher does an exam or a test to his/her pupils, in Spanish we say "tomar un examen". This depends on the point of view: because on the other hand, the student should say "dar un examen": "La maestra toma un examen a los alumnos"; "Los alumnos dan un examen".

Comment: @Nicolás In Spain it's different, we just say: "la maestra pone un examen a los alumnos" and "los alumnos hacen un examen".

Comment: ¿"tomar un examen a los alumnos"  para hacer un examen a los alumnos? In English, we say **give an exam to students** not do.

Answer (score 3):

The position of those pronouns before or after the verb is given by the rules which are in **the section 3 of this [link](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=pronombres%20personales%20%E1tonos) of RAE**.

A quick summary of what RAE says in that link:

**They have to go before the verb:**

- with verbs in indicative mood (it's archaic to place them after the verb):
- with verbs in subjuctive mood (for non exhorting verbs)

**They have to go after the verb:**

- with verbs in imperative mood
- with verbs in subjuctive mood (for exhorting verbs)
- with verbs in infinitive or gerund (in verbal periphrasis it usually can be placed also before).

In your example **you are using the verb dar in the indicative mood**. For that reason those pronouns should be placed before the verb. So the correct one would be:

> La maestra **nos lo da**.

You have to take into account that the word "da" can be a present of indicative but also an imperative:

> (Él/Ella) da - **present of indicative**
>
> da (tú) - **imperative**

So if you place the pronouns after the verb then people would think you are using imperative:

> Nos lo da --> He gives it to us
>
> Dánoslo --> Give it to us. (imperative)

So yor second sentence:

> La maestra dánoslo* (Incorrect)

would be incorrect because you can't use "la maestra" with an imperative.

Comment: "La maestra dánoslo" can be correct, but not as an imperative, but as an affirmative sentence. It's and oldish construction.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is the first one. Alternatively:

> Danoslo la maestra

But you'll rarely find this construct in prose.

Answer (score 0):

Although both forms are correct, the second one sounds extremely archaic/poetical. You should never attach pronouns in normal speech, the natural one is

> Nos lo da. (*She* gives it to us)

The exception are imperatives. Imperatives are **always attached**, otherwise you'd confuse an affirmative sentence with an order:

> ¡Dánoslo! (give us that)

(and don't forget the accent mark).

Answer (score 0):

The affirmative imperative command form attaches the direct or indirect pronoun to the conjugated verb.

I am teaching myself Spanish and found it virtually impossible to Google the explanation of the word dime.
What's worse, the social media results that lead results; Quora, Reddit all said the pronouns precede conjugated verbs.
Good luck googling accent placement.
Social media results are not accurate. A site like this I will trust.

Comment: That does not seem to add much to the existing much fuller answers.